# How to get similar meaning of text from csv file in R

Tags: data-science

Following is my code:

```
library(sentiment)
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr) 
library(tm)
library(Matrix)
library(syuzhet)

moviedata=read.csv('C:/Users/Sudeer/Desktop/movies1.csv',stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df<-data.frame(moviedata)
View(df)

class_pol = classify_polarity(moviedata, algorithm="bayes")
View(class_pol)
a<-subset(class_pol=)
# get polarity best fit

polarity = class_pol[,4]

# Create data frame with the results and obtain some general statistics

# data frame with results

sent_df = data.frame(text= moviedata,polarity=polarity,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

View(sent_df)
ggplot(sent_df, aes(x=polarity)) +geom_bar(aes(y=..count.., fill=polarity)) + scale_fill_brewer(palette="RdGy") + labs(x="polarity categories", y="text") + ggtitle("Movie classification")


pos<-subset(sent_df, sent_df$polarity=="positive")
```

Till now I get positive opinions from csv file. In csv file it contains film effecting indian youth. I separated positive negative netral opinions. from positive opinions i need similar meaning of text in R. please clarify.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is clear. Please try and say specifically what you  you are trying to do & what the problem is now.

Comment: Hi i need in csv file i classified positive negative neutral opinions.From positive opinions   i need similar meaning of text .How to get similar meaning of postive opinions text.For example in positive opinions some one wrote similar to my opinion. i need that similar meaning of text in R . How to do that